# Create Custom SSRS Reports Utilizing LINQ to CRM Dynamics 365 Online

Tags: sql-server, linq, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, x++

Okay hello all I am new here so forgive me for any unintentional fopas I may commit with this posting.

I have a design question concerning creating custom ssrs reports within dynamics 365 online. I have searched the net but I am unable to get any concrete answers.

My question is, is it possible to create custom ssrs reports utilizing linq to crm? if so, what are the exact limitations, what are the strengths and is there another design pattern that would be stronger than using linq to create custom ssrs report queries. I am currently in the beginning stages of creating a new ssrs system for my company, and we are looking for a good way to create user friendly ssrs reports within dynamics 365 online.

I must note that I am looking for suggestions concerning Dynamics 365 online as are database will be hosted in the cloud. Again forgive me for any incorrectness in the format of my question I am new to this forum.

Comment: I do not see this question as broad. I am asking for a specific answer, can linq crm be used to create a ssrs custom report. I just need a concrete answer, and on top of everything else this question will save other AX developers a lot time and pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and correct answer - I'm sorry but you can't do that. Reports for Dynamics 365 allow only FetchXml datasources.

Comment: Do you have an official source that states this fact? I can not located a site that gives a straight forward answer on this matter.

Comment: Following article states that you can have only 2 datasources for reports - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx SQL and FetchXml. The same page states following - For security reasons, you cannot deploy custom SQL-based reports to Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online). Based on this - FetchXml datasource is the only available datasource for Online instance of CRM.

Comment: Ok thank you for your assistance with this matter. Sucks that this is the only alternative for SSRS reports as you can only deploy custom reports using FetchXml.